# Can't read the txt file in to an array of objects and then print out the result

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, text-parsing

I am trying to read a file, in to an array of objects, from my `Movie class` and then print the results.

```
public class Movie_Class {
  private int MovieID;
  private String MovieTitle;
  private String Director;
  private String Writer;
  private String Duration;
  private String Genre;
  private String Classification;
  private String ReleaseDate;
  private Double Rating;

  public Movie_18512117(int ID, String Title, String Mdirector, String  Mwriter,
 String Mduration, String Mgenre, String Mclassification, String MreleaseDate, Double  Mrating) {

    MovieID = ID;
    MovieTitle= Title;
    Director= Mdirector;
    Writer= Mwriter;
    Duration= Mduration;
    Genre= Mgenre;
    Classification= Mclassification;
    ReleaseDate= MreleaseDate;
    Rating= Mrating;
  }

  public int  getMovieID(){
    return MovieID;
  }

  public String getMovieTitle(){
    return MovieTitle;
  }

  public String getDirector(){
    return Director;
  }

  public String getWriter(){
    return Writer;
  }

  public String getDuration(){
    return Duration;
  }

  public String getGenre(){
    return Genre;
  }

  public String getClassification(){
    return Classification;
  }

  public String getReleaseDate(){
    return ReleaseDate;
  }

  public Double  getRating(){
    return Rating;
  }

  public void setMovieID(int MovieID) {
    this.MovieID = MovieID;
  }

  public void  setMovieTitle(String MovieTitle){
    this.MovieTitle = MovieTitle;
  }

  public void  setDirector(String Director) {
    this.Director = Director;
  }

  public void  setWriter(String Writer) {
    this. Writer =  Writer;
  }

  public void  setDuration(String Duration) {
    this. Duration =  Duration;
  }

  public void  setGenre(String Genre) {
    this.Genre = Genre;
  }

  public void  setClassification(String Classification){
    this.Classification = Classification;
  }

  public void  setReleaseDate(String ReleaseDate){
    this.ReleaseDate = ReleaseDate;
  }

  public void  setRating(Double Rating){
    this.Rating = Rating;
  }
}

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class movie {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File myFile = new File ("movieLibrary.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
    String str;
    Movie_Class[] movie = new Movie_Class[100];
    String[] tokens;

    while (inputFile.hasNext()){
      str=inputFile.next();
      tokens = str.split(",");
      for(int i = 0; i < movies.length; i++){
        movie[i] = new Movie_18512117(1);

//I don't know how to read the lines in to //my array and split the spaces, then print the result.

        System.out.println(movie);
      }
    }
    inputFile.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)! Which problem occurred, that you're trying to fix?

Comment: You forgot to describe the problem and ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

try using the BufferedReader and FileReader classes instead of scanner if you want to iterate through an input stream like you do. In the link is an useful tutorial how to do this:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

also, you can use the ".split(regex)"  methode to further processes the incoming information from the file.
(e.g. split on spaces with String.split("\s+");)

As for adding to the information to the array; you could try ussing an ArrayList and its .add() methode instead of the object Array your using now.

Answer (score 0):

Your constructor method for `Movie_Class` should be `public Movie_Class`, not `public Movie_18512117`. That's first mistake. Read more about [constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html).
Then you can create a new `Movie_Class` object by calling

```
movie[i] = new Movie_Class(...);
```

In the constructor, you have to input all the details of the movie, not just the `ID`. If you want to create a movie object with only ID, you should define a new constructor with only `ID` as the input value, like following

```
public Movie_Class (int ID) {
  // Do whatever you want
}
```

You can use ArrayList instead of an Array, if you want to add objects, without knowing the exact number of elements you should store in it. Read about *ArrayLists* and other *Collections* [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/).
Try to fix these errors first. Then you can go on.